# How to make text_area_tag disabled set to true for RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build my own simple calculator app using RoR.

This is my initial draft of my code.

```
<h1>Welcome to Andy's awesome simple calculator</h1>
<% provide(:title, "Simple Calculator")%>


<div class="calculator">
    Calculator
<%= form_tag do %>  
<div class="output-screen">
    <%= text_area_tag :output,:disabled=>true %>
</div>

<div class="panel-buttons-container">

<div class="operator-buttons">
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, 'C') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '*') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '/') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '-') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '+') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '()') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '=') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, 'DEL') end %>
</div>
<div class="decimal-buttons">
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '1') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '2') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '3') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '4') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '5') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '6') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '7') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '8') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '9') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '0') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '.') end %>
    <%= button_tag(type:'button') do content_tag(:strong, '+/-') end %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

The thing that puzzled me the most now is why couldn't have **text_area_tag** be disabled?  I followed the Ruby on Rails documentation on form helpers, back and forth.  But I could't get the correct result!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could also try rolling up those loops with like `'1'..'0'.each{ button... }`, but that's properly a subject for the review forum ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
<%= text_area_tag :output, nil, :disabled=>true %>
```

The second parameter to [`text_area_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_area_tag) is `content` which needs to be specified for the `options` to work, one of the `options` being `disabled`.

Comment: Great!.  Thanks for that Vee!  Makes so much sense now.  Couldn't believe it's actually that trivial to fix!

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of text_area_tag is value so write it like this:

```
<%= text_area_tag :output, nil, :disabled=>true %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag